# Unable To Bypass Pattern Lock After Encryption

Tags: encryption

I tried encrypting my android phone and I end up with a screen with "draw pattern to start android" the pattern box is so small (ref : IMG ) after 20-30 attempts finally I draw my pattern "starting android" & power on logo screen and stuck.

What to do

Answer (score 2):

Try booting into recovery mode and performing a factory reset. Normally to boot into recovery the key combination is <kbd>VOL_DOWN+POWER</kbd>

Comment: Tried but no result! Power + Vol Down Draw pattern end up with white screen